# Octave not returning exit code

Tags: octave, exit-code

Under Lubuntu 18.04 and Octave 4.2.2, this script

```
#!/usr/bin/octave

exit(1);
```

executed from the command line with

```
$ ./exitscript.m
```

always returns this output

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'octave::exit_exception'
panic: Aborted -- stopping myself...
attempting to save variables to 'octave-workspace'...
save to 'octave-workspace' complete
octave exited with signal 6
```

and prompting for exit code (right after executing the command)

```
$ echo $?
```

always returns 0, ignoring the value passed to the system.

Related [bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?50664).

Comment: What is the reason to add an ancient version? Try to add --no-qui to the shebang

Comment: @Andy same result, only that now `$?` returns 134, independently of the exit code in the script. 0 output as well for `-nq`.  As for the version, if you mean Octave, that's the latest that installs with Lubuntu 18.04, the distro and version where the `exit` command is needed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug in Octave 4.2. `exit` shouldn't crash. (Surprise!)

Looks like it's been fixed in newer versions of Octave, starting with Octave 4.4.0. I think you need to just upgrade, here.

Unfortunately, most Linux distros ship with quite old versions of Octave. To get a more recent Octave version, you can install a 4.4.x or 5.1.x Octave [using Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.octave.Octave) or build it from source.